# jQuery convert .each() into for()

Tags: jquery

I've found a jQuery plugin which does exactly what I want but it takes too long to do it.  I can see that there are instances of `.each()` being used which are 10 times slower than `for()` - item 3 in this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/).

What's the best way of converting those `.each` into `.for()` please?

E.g.:

```
    $firstTdChildren = $fixedBody.find(firstTdChildrenSelector)
        .each(function(index) {
            helpers._fixHeightWithCss($(this), tableProps);
            helpers._fixWidthWithCss($(this), tableProps, tdWidths[index % settings.fixedColumns] );
    });
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Unless you  got thousands it won't make any change, anyway, SO isn't a code review\ code changes service.

Comment: What is your way of converting `.each` into `.for()`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, hence the question.

Comment: @user417627, `.find()` returns array of jQuery object, why would you want to access it using `for`?

Comment: Because the tutorial I was reading said that it's better to use for than each, but I'm not clear how to do it.  Are you saying it can't be done?

Comment: am betting you won't visually notice much difference... problem is likely deeper rooted

Comment: NO it is possible but the use however I believe misleaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in converting the code unless you have hundreds and hundreds of items to iterate through. Furthermore, there are other ways to save overall time such as minimizing the script to save page load time.

To convert, .each is just going through each item. So in jQuery:

```
var elms[];
for (var i = 0; i < $("div").get().length; i++) {
    alert($("div").innerHTML);
  }
```